# Generic object Deserialization and Serialization java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

Hello I am learning Generics and I having trouble deserializing an object(s) back from a file into a generic list and then printing.

result is an empty screen, even though i know that a dat file was created

I've tried a variety of ways.

My utilizes frames with ActionListener..

This is the  ActionListener

```
 private class AddButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // variables    
        String inputfName;
        String inputlName;
        String idInput;
        //String studentID;

        // capture input
        inputfName = sFirstName.getText();
        inputlName = sLastName.getText();
        idInput = sID.getText();

        //hold Student data


        //convert to Int
        //studentID = Integer.parseInt(idInput);

        //Create file
        StudentAddProcess sFile = new StudentAddProcess();
        sFile.writesFile(inputfName, inputlName, idInput );

    }
```

This these process the input

public class StudentAddProcess implements Serializable{

```
    String inputFirstName ;
    String inputLastName;
     String  inputID;


private Component Frame;

// Create File 
public void  writesFile ( String fName, String  lName, String Id ){

    // create T fields for student

     inputFirstName = fName;
     inputLastName = lName;
     inputID = Id;


try {


    ObjectOutputStream objectInputFile = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);

    //Linkeked List of Student Objects
    GenericLinkedList<Student> studentList = new GenericLinkedList<>();

    // add Student Object to student 
    studentList.add(new Student(inputID, inputFirstName, inputLastName));

    //Where am i
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame, "writing ...");

    //  for loop cycle and write student to fill

        for (int i =0 ;  i < studentList.size();i++) {
            objectInputFile.writeObject(studentList.get(i));
        }

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame, "Complete :");
       //close file 
       objectInputFile.close();
```

Now we view the added object

```
    public class StudentViewFile implements Serializable {

    //variables 
    private String studentID; // holds passed user request to view
    private Component Frame;

    public void readFile(String  sID) throws IOException {

    studentID = sID;  // take passed variable
    //int studentID2 =Integer.getInteger(sID);

    try {
        //open read file 


        FileInputStream inStream = new         FileInputStream("StudentObjects.dat");// Stream of Objects

        ObjectInputStream objectInputFile = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);

       GenericLinkedList <Student> readRecord = new  GenericLinkedList<>();

         readRecord.add(new Student(studentID));

        for (int i = 0; i < readRecord.size(); i++) {
            readRecord = (GenericLinkedList) objectInputFile.readObject();

            // Diplay  records 
            System.out.println("File Objects" + readRecord.get(i) + " \n   next positions");

             // was going to try to print my test here  

            System.out.println(readRecord.toString());
        }

        // Read the serialized objects from the file.
        while (true) {

           readRecord = (GenericLinkedList) objectInputFile.readObject();



            // Display  records 
            System.out.println( "File Objects" + readRecord+ " \n next positions");

            //close file 
           objectInputFile.close();
          }

       } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.print("\n Exception caught ");
```

Any ideas would be great . Thank you in advance for your time and knowledge

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `ObjectOutputStream objectInputFile = ` is a bizarre choice of variable name!  It is guaranteed to confuse someone trying to reading your code.

Comment: Why are you initializing and adding to a list that you are immediately reassigning?

Answer (score 1):

Compare the way that you are writing the objects with the way that you are attempting to read them.

```
    for (int i =0 ;  i < studentList.size();i++) {
        objectInputFile.writeObject(studentList.get(i));
    }
```

This writes a sequence of `Student` objects.

```
    readRecord = (GenericLinkedList) objectInputFile.readObject();
```

This attempts to read something and cast it to `GenericLinkedList`.  But it won't be one of those.  It will actually be a `Student`, so you will get an exception.

The other problem is this:

```
    GenericLinkedList <Student> readRecord = new  GenericLinkedList<>();
    readRecord.add(new Student(studentID));
    for (int i = 0; i < readRecord.size(); i++) {
        readRecord = (GenericLinkedList) objectInputFile.readObject();
```

How many times do you really want to go round the loop?  Where is that number actually coming from?

There are a number of ways to deal with this; for example:

1. Write (and then read) the entire list as a single object
2. Start the stream by writing the list size (`studentList.size()`) as an `int`.  When reading, first read the list size, and then read that number of `Student` objects.
3. Read using a `while (true)` loop and catch / handle the `EOFException`.

(I note that you have attempted to do alternative 3 ... following the broken code.  Of course that won't get past your broken code, so that won't work.  What *are* you thinking?)

Comment: The number loops comes while the the last node is not null

Comment: Well at least thats what i wanr

Comment: Well that's NOT what your code actually does.  Read it carefully.  What it is currently doing is actually nonsensical.  I have given you three ways to it correctly: use one of those.

Comment: So i was going to catch the exceptions generated by the read/write file . I will have to try to extrapolate from your post i guess. I think the big problem you nailed . Casting the wrong object...

Comment: Yes you do.  I am NOT going to write your code for you.  This is clearly a "learning exercise" and you will learn a lot more if you understand, code and test it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, look at this code below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main {

    private static class GenericLinkedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {

    }

    private static class Student implements Serializable {

        final String name;

        public Student(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try(ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            try(ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {

                GenericLinkedList<Student> students = new GenericLinkedList<>();

                seed(students);

                objectOutputStream.writeObject(students);

                try(ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()))) {

                    Object readObject = objectInputStream.readObject();

                    GenericLinkedList<Student> readStudents = (GenericLinkedList<Student>) readObject;

                    for (Student student : readStudents) {
                        System.out.println(student.getName());
                    }

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void seed(GenericLinkedList<Student> students) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            students.add(new Student("test #" + i));
        }
    }

}
```

It normally works with generic list. [Try this code](http://ideone.com/vAO6n5) by yourself

Comment: Thx u for all the replies i will return the knowledge once i have it . I will try these and get post back

Answer (score 0):

When you serialized the list to file, you serialized each student object in the list through a loop.

```
    for (int i =0 ;  i < studentList.size();i++) {
        objectInputFile.writeObject(studentList.get(i));
    }
```

So when you deserialized it, and you should deserialize the students one by one, rather than the whole list

```
    GenericLinkedList <Student> readRecord = new  GenericLinkedList<>();
    Student student;
    while (true) {
        student = (Student) objectInputFile.readObject();
        // Display  records 
        System.out.println( "File Objects" + student + " \n next positions");
        readRecord.add(student);
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.print("\n Exception caught ");
        //close file 
        objectInputFile.close();
    }
```